# What's a good webrtc audio solution?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

There's opentok and vline for webrtc video is there a similar service just for audio? Or can you use these apis in a restricted way?

If not, is there an open source javascript library / tutorial that can get me started with building 1-1 and 1-many audio connections over webrtc?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the vLine API you can do audio-only calls (as well as combinations such as one side sending audio and video and the other side only sending audio).

If you're using the "Web Client" you can click on the small arrow next to the "Video Call" button to make an audio-only call (there is a similar drop-down when answering a call).

If you're using the [vLine API](https://vline.com/developer/docs/low_level_intro), you can use the [`vline.MediaConstraints`](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.MediaConstraints) to do an audio-only call when calling [`vline.Person.startMedia()`](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.Channel#startMedia).